# Can't import bean validation annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working in a spring boot application with spring boot version 2.3 with following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I want to use the NonNull or NotBlank annotations I can't import:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
```

Normally I shouldn't need an extra dependency apparently because it's already included in starter data jpa but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to run `mvn clean install -U`

Comment: It isn't included in the dependencies, you need to add `spring-boot-starter-validation`. Which prior to 2.3 was part of `spring-boot-starter-web` but has been removed from that as of Spring Boot 2.3. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters

Comment: Thank you! If you answer the question I will mark it as solved so you get reputation.